# Chrome OS and Ubuntu dual boot

Tags: dual-boot, 20.04, chromeos

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. I want to use Chrome OS alongside my Ubuntu. All the videos I have seen include involvement of Windows 10 and Linux Mint and those are about triple booting. Can someone show me the exact way of installing and dual booting ChromeOS with Ubuntu only?

Comment: Generally booting more than a single OS is called dual booting (even if it's three or four operating systems, it's the OS that is running with the alternate OSes that aren't running counted as the other option(s)). You (1) install the single OS, (2) then install/add the second, for three you just repeat the second step. You only need not repeating adding another OS to your system.

Comment: You will probably want to use the chromium OS, since chrome OS usually not available for download.  Research more into this before trying.  Make space on drive to make a new partition and double check everything before installing